# Integrate PHP code in Smarty templates

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

I use Smarty to implement my template. How can I write this PHP sentence.

`<?php if(empty($_GET['action'])) { echo class="current"; } ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template engines were invented to separate business logic (and the request itself) from presentational logic. Template engine should not take care of $_GET, $_POST, $_SESSION, etc.

If you need to make a decision based on $_GET['action'] - then just pass it from your controller with reguler smarty's `assign`.

Anyway, if you don't want your code to be more logical and obvious you could use `$smarty.get.action`

```
{if empty($smarty.get.action)}class="current"{/if}
```

Comment: thanks! i want to assign a value to `$_GET['action'] = 'detail'` I wrote: `{if ($smarty.get.action='detail') class="current"{/if}` but I get an error

Comment: @Mini: `{if ($smarty.get.action eq 'detail') class="current"{/if}`

Comment: @zerkms: thanks I use `{if ($smarty.get.action=='details')} class="current"{/if}` what's the best == or eq ? thanks

Comment: @Mini: they are synonyms. I used to use `eq`.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks :) where I can found all functions and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
{if !isset($smarty.get.action)}class="current"{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to use `if($_GET['action'] == 'open') {}` there is a manual or docs?

Comment: Aye.  Here's some docs that should be useful:  http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl and http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.request

Comment: Wow so easy. I just found the correct code `{if ($smarty.get.action=='details')} class="current"{/if}` :)

Comment: Perfect!  Though you shouldn't need the parenthesis if you want to save two characters in typing :D